# A polling wrapper for Python's socket library

Tags: python, socket

Even though I am working with one socket, I have wrapped it with an object which allows `.recv()` method which accepts timeout, using Python's `select.poll()`.

The initialization of the wrapping object defines a socket using the address/protocol family, of type stream; then it connects, flags it as non-blocking and registers it to a poll object. So the `.__init__()` method looks like this:

```
def __init__(self, host, port):
    self.host = host
    self.port = port
    self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.poll = select.poll()
    event_in_mask = select.POLLIN | select.POLLPRI
    event_err_mask = select.POLLERR                                 
    event_closed_mask = select.POLLHUP | select.POLLNVAL
    event_mask = event_in_mask | event_err_mask | event_closed_mask
    self.poll.register(self.socket, event_mask)
```

I mask the poll object as I am interested in querying only incoming data or errors.

The receive method will look like this:

```
def recv(self, timeout):
    events = self.poll.poll(timeout)
    if not events:
        return ""
    event = events[0][1]

    ## Invalid request; descriptor not open
    if event & select.POLLNVAL:
        err = "Invalid request; descriptor not open"
        raise ConnectionClosedError(err, host=self.host, port=self.port)

    ## Hung up
    if event & select.POLLHUP:
        err = "Hung up"
        raise ConnectionClosedError(err, host=self.host, port=self.port)

    ## Error condition of some sort
    if event & select.POLLERR:
        err = "Error condition of some sort"
        raise ConnectionClosedError(err, host=self.host, port=self.port)

    ## There is data to read
    ready = event & select.POLLPRI or event & select.POLLIN

    ## Timeout expiry; nothing was received, we pass an empty string
    if not ready:
        return ""

    return self._recv()
```

The `._recv()` method simply calls `self.socket.recv(4096)` with some error catching.

And finally, the `.close()` method will look like that:

```
def close(self):
    self.poll.unregister(self.socket)
    self.socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
    self.socket.close()
```

My questions are:

- is there anything redundant here?
- is polling the right choice? (I've used `select.select()` before, but it has caused some issues)
- do you think the general architecture makes sense?

**EDIT:** The `ConnectionClosedError` is some custom `Exception` that wraps the socket exception just for convenience.

## The Complete Code

```
## Framework
import select
import socket


###################################
## ----- Connection Errors ----- ##
###################################
import errno


class ConnectionError(IOError):
  def __init__(self, err, host=None, port=None):
    self.err = err
    self.host = host
    self.port = port

  err_msg = "{self.err}"

  def __str__(self):
    return self.err_msg.format(self=self)


class ConnectionClosedError(ConnectionError):
  err_msg = "Connection closed (host '{self.host}', port {self.port})"


class ConnectionRefusedError(ConnectionError):
  err_msg = "{self.err} (host '{self.host}', port {self.port})"


########################
## ----- Client ----- ##
########################

class SocketClient(object):
  """ Low level socket client. """
  def __init__(self, host, port, blocking=False):
    self.host = host
    self.port = port
    self.blocking = blocking

    ## Initialize socket
    try:
      self.init_socket()

    ## Couldn't
    except socket.error as socket_error:

      ## Connection was refused
      if socket_error.errno == errno.ECONNREFUSED:
        raise ConnectionRefusedError(socket_error, host=self.host,
                                     port=self.port)

      ## There was some other socket problem
      raise ConnectionError(socket_error)

  def init_socket(self):
    """ Instantiate a local socket and connect it with a remote
    socket. """
    ## AF_INET is a constant representing the address/protocol family
    ## SOCK_STREAM is a constant representing the socket type
    ## The function returns a Socket object
    self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    ## Connect to server (a remote socket)
    ## The format of the address depends on the address family. In the case of
    ## AF_INET, it is a pair (host, port), where 'host' is a string
    ## representing either a hostname in internet domain notation like
    ## 'daring.cwi.nl' or an IPv4 address like '100.50.200.5', and port is an
    ## integer.
    try:
      self.socket.connect((self.host, self.port))
    except TypeError:
      if not isinstance(self.port, int):
        raise ConnectionError("port must be int (got {})".format(self.port))

    ## We set the socket to non-blocking mode
    if not self.blocking:
      self.socket.setblocking(0)

    ## We construct a polling object and register the socket
    self.poll = select.poll()
    event_in_mask = select.POLLIN | select.POLLPRI
    event_err_mask = select.POLLERR
    event_closed_mask = select.POLLHUP | select.POLLNVAL
    event_mask = event_in_mask | event_err_mask | event_closed_mask
    self.poll.register(self.socket, event_mask)

  def close(self):
    """ Close the socket. """
    ## Unregister the socket
    self.poll.unregister(self.socket)

    self.socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
    self.socket.close()

  def _recv(self):
    """ A thin wrapper around the socket's recv method. """
    ## Receive data from socket
    ## 4096 comes from a recommendation in the python module documentation
    ## for the socket module
    try:
      return self.socket.recv(4096)

    ## Couldn't receive
    except socket.error as socket_error:

      ## Connection was closed
      if socket_error.errno == errno.EBADF:
        raise ConnectionClosedError(socket_error, host=self.host,
                                    port=self.port)

      ## There was some other socket problem
      raise ConnectionError(socket_error)

  def recv(self, timeout=None):
    """ Receive data from socket. If *timeout* is given, smartly return an
    empty string after *timeout* seconds have passed. """
    ## If not timeout was given, we think of the socket as if it is ready now
    if not timeout:
      return self._recv()

    ## Otherwise, we poll the socket, to check if there is data to read
    events = self.poll.poll(timeout)

    ## If no events were returned, socket is not ready
    if not events:
      return ""

    ## Otherwise, we're interested only in one event and we query it
    event = events[0][1]

    ## Invalid request; descriptor not open
    if event & select.POLLNVAL:
      err = "Invalid request; descriptor not open"
      raise ConnectionClosedError(err, host=self.host, port=self.port)

    ## Hung up
    if event & select.POLLHUP:
      err = "Hung up"
      raise ConnectionClosedError(err, host=self.host, port=self.port)

    ## Error condition of some sort
    if event & select.POLLERR:
      err = "Error condition of some sort"
      raise ConnectionClosedError(err, host=self.host, port=self.port)

    ## There is data to read
    ready = event & select.POLLPRI or event & select.POLLIN

    ## Timeout expiry; nothing was received, we pass an empty string
    if not ready:
      return ""

    ## Ready? Query socket
    return self._recv()

  def send(self, string):
    """ Send *string* to the socket. Continue to send data from *string* until
    either all data has been sent or an error occurs. Return ``None`` on
    success, raise on failure. """
    ## We use 'sendall' as we do not wish to allow partial messages
    self.socket.sendall(string)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks okay in general.  One set of lines that gave me pause was:

```
## We set the socket to non-blocking mode
if not self.blocking:
  self.socket.setblocking(0)
```

it looked redundant until I realized this was initial socket configuration.  So it might be a little clearer if you did something like:

```
self.socket.setblocking(1 if self.blocking else 0)
```

or even

```
self.socket.setblocking(int(self.blocking))
```

I think unconditionally setting it to something drives home the fact that it's a configuration step.